# Rails console on first/all/last showing object relation and not values of the object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, sqlite, console

When I call my first model lead in the console:

```
Lead.first
```

it gives me the correct output:

```
Lead Load (1.2ms)  SELECT  "leads".* FROM "leads" ORDER BY "leads"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
 => #<Lead id: 2070, company: "Schobertechnologies GmbH", industry: "Tool manufacturer", street: "Industriestraße 2", zip: "71735", city: "Eberdingen", country: "Germany", phone: "+49 7042 7900", website: "http://www.schobertechnologies.de/", linkedin: nil, created_at: "2020-02-19 11:41:20", updated_at: "2020-02-19 11:41:20", customer_id: "bcommand", slug: "schobertechnologiesgmbh">
```

Another Model company

```
Company.first
```

shows

```
 Company Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "companies".* FROM "companies" ORDER BY "companies"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
 => #<Company >
```

In the view the values for company are displayed correctly. This is the schema file.

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2020_06_15_081229) do

  create_table "Companies", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "company"
    t.string "industry"
    t.string "street"
    t.string "zip"
    t.string "city"
    t.string "country"
    t.string "phone"
    t.string "website"
    t.string "linkedin"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "customer_id"
    t.string "slug"
  end

  create_table "ipblacklists", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "blacklistedip"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "customer_id"
  end

  create_table "leads", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "company"
    t.string "industry"
    t.string "street"
    t.string "zip"
    t.string "city"
    t.string "country"
    t.string "phone"
    t.string "website"
    t.string "linkedin"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "customer_id"
    t.string "slug"
    t.index ["customer_id", "slug"], name: "index_leads_on_customer_id_and_slug"
  end

  create_table "trackings", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "ip"
    t.string "url"
    t.string "customer_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "visits", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "lead_id"
    t.string "url"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["lead_id"], name: "index_visits_on_lead_id"
  end

end
```

Company.first should be showing the values of the object as well? What is going on here?

Answer (score 3):

Rails creates a *lowercase* table name from a class name.
So it maps your `Company` class to the table named `companies`

When you run `Company.first` you can see in the query generated that it is looking for a lower case table named **"companies"**:

```
...  SELECT  "companies".* FROM "companies" ORDER BY "companies"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
```

But in your schema, you have created an *uppercase* named table:

```
create_table "Companies",
```

That may be the problem.

Comment: Yes, this might be the issue. Could I just create a migration to name the table or what would be a correct procedure here?

Comment: You should be able to rename the table with a migration.  See the `rename_table` method in the "Using the change method" section of the Rails migrations guide: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#using-the-change-method

Out of curiosity, what does your migration look like when you first created that table with the uppercase name?  (Looking at that can help you learn what to not do in the future.)

Answer (score 0):

Try to run rake db:migrate:down VERSION=(migration file version) and do rake db:migrate again.